# Mantis Bug Tracking system

Tags: system, bug-tracking, mantis

I know its a silly question but I have no idea of how bug tracking systems work, I know what they are used for though. Research showed me that mantis is simpler to use over Bugzilla so I decided to use mantis but have no idea how to install it.Can anyone please tell me what are the steps  you need to take in order to install mantis bug tracking system in a small company to track website, mobile portal bugs?

Comment: Fair warning. This question will probably get deleted. That being said. I have installed Mantis locally before and it was pretty straight-forward. You can follow the documentation here: http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide.html#ADMIN.INSTALL

Comment: it's not a programming question

Comment: ohh ok Thanks a lot, I dint know you can post only programming questions, I have seen discussion on bug tracking systems here

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you genuinely mean well so I'll try to help

I assume you're working with a developer? Ask them to set up a bug tracker, you might be able to find some kind of lighter solution like a shared google doc with some conditional formats you can make a pretty effective bug reporting/tracking solution

Another easy and actually very good option is using an online service like Bugherd.  I actually highly recommend Bugherd, for a small cost you can actually put markers on the website with notes.  Developers can see a list of reports and go to the screen you were viewing with the marker on the problem, very nice software.  Can be installed to site, doesn't need to be, I prefer to use it with the bookmark option to load when needed.

If you're set on hosting your own you'll need to get a machine to act as a host for it, install some kind of web server to it like apache or IIS (for windows)

Once you have that you should be able to follow the relevant instructions for installing your bugtracker of choice, if not hire a consultant or something like that perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Read the [administration guide](http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/master-1.2.x/en/administration_guide.html)

I think this explanation is as good as it gets

Answer (score 0):

Choosing Mantis over Bugzilla was a smart move.

For installing Mantis on your local machine you would need to install a wamp server.

**Wamp server installation link**- http://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/WampServer%202.2/wampserver2.2e/wampserver2.2e-php5.4.3-httpd2.2.22-mysql5.5.24-32b.exe/download

After this, open your wamp folder you will find a www folder with in Var.

Now you need to paste your mantis folder in this www folder.

**For finding Mantis**- http://sourceforge.net/projects/mantisbt/files/mantis-stable/

- Download and extract the zip file.
- Paste the extracted file in your www folder

**After this for installation**

- Start your wamp server.
- Open a browser and in the URL type **localhost/name of the mantis folder/index.php**

Let me know if you have any further issues.